# Inconstant number of parameters in stored-proc-outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am building an application (using spring-integration) which is supposed to recieve Request object from whatever-inbound-gateway and call MS SQL stored procedure.
The Request object contains `String` attribute `procedureName` and `List<Pair<String, Object>>` attribute `parameters`. The problem is that I can't find a solution, how to pass List of parameters when I don't know it's length at compile time.
Config for outbound gateway:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="outbound-gateway-procedure" request-channel="requestChannel"
        data-source="dataSource" stored-procedure-name-expression="payload.procedureName"
        sql-parameter-source-factory="someParameterSourceFactory" >

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

If I knew that I have exactly 2 parameters in the list and their names are 'first' and 'second', I would configure `sql-parameter-source-factory` the way like this:

```
<bean id="someParameterSourceFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="first" value-type="java.lang.String" value="payload.parameters.get(1).second"/>
            <entry key="second" value-type="java.lang.String" value="payload.parameters.get(2).second"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But i do not know neither number of parameters no their names at compile time. Any suggestions?

**UPD:**
Stored procedure looks like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[pnzLimitUtilization_Show]
(
     @BookDate          datetime      
   , @LegalGroupList    varchar(4000)  
   , @Currency          char(3) 
   , @FilterForAny      nvarchar(255) = '' 
   , @RiskZone          char(1)      = 'A'
   , @WithZerroExposure char(1)      = '0'  
   , @Transliteration   bit          = 0 
   , @IsNewMethodology  bit          = 0       
   , @UtilizationType   char(1)      = 'A'
   , @PartyGroupList    varchar(255) = NULL             
   , @HostName          varchar(255) = NULL           
   , @ShowCloseExpiration bit = 0 
   , @CloseExpirationDays int = 90 
   , @WhatIfDealFilter   char(1)         = 'R'               
   , @HideLESublimits   bit          = 0
)
as begin ....
```

New config:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="outbound-gateway-procedure" request-channel="requestChannel"
        data-source="dataSource" stored-procedure-name-expression="payload.name.toString()"
        ignore-column-meta-data="true"
        sql-parameter-source-factory="listParameterSourceFactory"
        reply-channel="replyChannel">
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

<bean id="listParameterSourceFactory" class="my.pack.integration.ListSqlParameterSourceFactory" />
```

ListSqlParameterSourceFactory:

```
public class ListSqlParameterSourceFactory implements SqlParameterSourceFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        GetSourceDataRequest message = (GetSourceDataRequest) input;
        List<NamedValueEntity> params = message.getParameters();
        MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        for (NamedValueEntity param : params) {
            source.addValue(param.getName().toString(), param.getValue());
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function 'pnzLimitUtilization_Show' expects parameter '@BookDate', which was not supplied.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
```

I debuged thru ListSqlParameterSourceFactory and it worked as expected, SqlParameterSource was

```
[0] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4243}"@Currency" -> "R"
[1] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4246}"@LegalGroupList" -> "( ALL )"
[2] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4249}"@FilterForAny" -> ""
[3] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4252}"@ShowCloseExpiration" -> "0"
[4] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4255}"@IsNewMethodology" -> "0"
[5] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4258}"@CloseExpirationDays" -> "0"
[6] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4261}"@WhatIfDealFilter" -> "R"
[7] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4264}"@UtilizationType" -> "A"
[8] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4267}"@BookDate" -> "20141202 00:00:00.000"
[9] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4270}"@Transliteration" -> "0"
[10] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4273}"@PartyGroupList" -> "( ALL )"
[11] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4276}"@RiskZone" -> "L"
[12] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@4279}"@HideLESublimits" -> "0"
```

Is there anything I missed?

**UPD2:**
Spring-jdbc log:

```
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show()}]
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall - SqlCall for procedure [dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show] compiled
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG CallMetaDataContext - Matching [@FilterForAny, @BookDate, @Currency, @UtilizationType, @HideLESublimits, @ShowCloseExpiration, @Transliteration, @IsNewMethodology, @RiskZone, @WhatIfDealFilter, @CloseExpirationDays, @PartyGroupList, @LegalGroupList] with []
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG CallMetaDataContext - Found match for []
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG SimpleJdbcCall - The following parameters are used for call {call dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show()} with: {}
05 dec 2014 14:15:28 DEBUG JdbcTemplate - Calling stored procedure [{call dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show()}]
```

Looks like it didn't pass any parameters..
Debugging CallMetaDataContext I found out that `this.callParameters` is empty. Isn't it connected with `ignore-column-meta-data="true"`? But if I switch it to `false` I see another error:

```
05 dec 2014 14:41:33 DEBUG CallMetaDataProviderFactory - Using org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.SqlServerCallMetaDataProvider
05 dec 2014 14:41:33 DEBUG CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieving metadata for null/null/dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show
05 dec 2014 14:41:36 DEBUG DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature for dbo.pnzLimitUtilization_Show - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName("dbo")'
```

**UPD3:**
Ok, I removed `dbo.` from procedure name and `@` from parameter names and now it correctly loads column metadata and bind variables. It does not mean that my application works but at least I can go further. Artem's suggestion helped to solve main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all how does your PROCEDURE look? At least specification.

Why are you sure that any list of parameters is legitimate for your procedure invocation?

From other side you go right way with the `SqlParameterSourceFactory` customization, but it really should fully custom implementation. Something like this, since you say that your `payload` has `parameters` property:

```
public class PairSqlParameterSourceFactory implements SqlParameterSourceFactory {


    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        Message<Request> message = (Message<Request>) input;
        List<Pair<String, Object>> pairs = message.getPayload().getParameters();
        MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        for (Pair<String, Object> pair : pairs) { 
            source.addValue(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
        }
        return source;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work still. Could you, please, have a look at updated post?

Comment: I see. You really missed the order of parameters. `@BookDate` is the first of of procedure spec. But in your `SqlParameterSource ` it is on the `[8]` position.

Comment: Artem, but if we go deeper inside `MapSqlParameterSource` we will see that it keeps parameters in usual `HashMap` which is not ordered. From javadocs: _This class is intended for passing in a simple Map of parameter values to the methods of the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class._ So I expect that Spring will bind parameters by names. Actually, I pass parameters in proper order, HashMap does all the mess

Comment: Note, we are here with `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`, so there is no any `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but just `SimpleJdbcCall#execute()`. Try to switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.jdbc` category to trace the state around your procedure preparation and provided args.